# How to cut off 5% of the highest and lowest values

Tags: r, trim

My question is pretty simple. I would like to cut off 5% of the highest and lowest values.
Here is my sample data set.

```
x = rnorm(100)
x_sorted = sort(x, decreasing = F)
```

I tried to apply the trim function. But unfortunately this function just works if I want to generate trimmed means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `quantile` to calculate value at 5% and 95% of `x` and then subset the values which lie between them.

```
x[x > quantile(x, 0.05) & x < quantile(x, 0.95)]
```